# Comparing classifiers using McNemar Test

Tags: machine-learning, classification, model-evaluation, mcnemar-test

When comparing the performance of two binary classifiers using McNemar test, should the two confusion matrices of the models be based on the training set, the validation set, or even a second validation set that was not used for parameter tuning? What is the justification for the correct approach?

Comment: no, it's a legitimate question. I read some papers on this like http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=21D16E681FF16B0BA91D741A63806A31?doi=10.1.1.29.5194&rep=rep1&type=pdf. They use the term "test data" but it is ambiguous.

Comment: Ah.  In that case, you should at least use a validation set, or better yet a second validation set, as you described.  You can also cross-validate.

Comment: I think you can either use it in the validation set or a second validation set(or test set). In the first case, you treat two models with different parameters or hyperparameters as different models while in the second case you may treat two models differing in model structure as two different models.

Comment: And there is only one matrix(or contingency table), not two.

Comment: @LernerZhang, why not turn those comments into an official answer?

Comment: McNemar's test is for purely categorical variables.  You seem to be forcing predictions into categories in order to use information-losing predictive accuracy scores.  Are you sure that forced-choice classification is appropriate for your goals, vs. continuous risk prediction?  https://fharrell.com/post/classification

Answer (score 0):

I think you can either use it in the validation set or a second validation set(or test set). In the first case, you treat two models with different parameters or hyperparameters as different models while in the second case you may treat two models differing in model structure as two different models.

And there is only one matrix(or contingency table), not two.